# Does transitioning to ChannelInactive state clear the Pipeline in Netty?

Tags: java, tcp, netty

Does the transition of a `Channel` into the `ChannelInactive` state clear the associated pipeline? In a unit test, I'm observing that after a handler is added and then a client disconnects, attempting to remove the handler results in `NoSuchElementFoundException`. I'm struggling to explain this behavior and any guidance would be much appreciated.

My model of the possible Channel state's comes from "Netty in Action" which provides this diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes once a `Channel` becomes inactive and unregistered it will teardown the `ChannelPipeline` which means it will remove all previous added handlers.